Is it true that the arbitrary $k$ columns in a $k \times n$ matrix (rank $k$, $k < n$) are linearly independent?
Let $G$ be a $k \times n$ matrix with rank $k$, where $k < n$. Then there exists at least one set of $k$ linearly independent columns in $G$. The question is, how many sets of $k$ linearly independent columns are there in $G$?
Or, is it true that the arbitrary $k$ columns in $G$ are linearly independent?

Try some simple examples. Start with $k=1$ and $k=2$.

not any $k$ columns will be independent.   this is pretty obvious.

You can have $n-k$ columns of all zeros, and still have rank $k$.

@GerryMyerson Yes, it is an intuitive example.

But how many sets of $k$ linearly independent columns in $G$?

Could be anywhere from one to all of them.

Agree with Gerry. But with the caveat that over a finite field there is a maximum for $n$ such that any collection of $k$ columns are linearly independent. For example, if $k=2$, and the field $F$ has $q$ elements, we get an upper bound $n\le q+1$ simply because there are only $q+1$ lines through the origin in the plane $F^2$. If two columns are on the same line, then those two columns are linearly dependent.
